# Using loop pagination on single.php

Tags: php, loop, query-posts, pagination, single

I want the main front-page loop to show in a section on both `index.php` AND `single.php` templates, with pagination.

Pagination works fine on the homepage, but not on single posts. This is the code (outside the loop that gets the single post):

```
query_posts(array(
  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
  'caller_get_posts' => 1,
  'posts_per_page' => 20,
  'paged' => ''.get_query_var('paged').'' ));
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  include 'post.php';
endwhile; endif;
get_previous_posts_link();
get_next_posts_link();
```

I have tried several other functions for navigation with similar results: On posts, `/page/2` is added to the end of the permalink and then ignored.

(Final goal is to have infinite scroll working inside single posts too. The result up to now can be seen here - www.riscograma.ro - the middle column being the main loop.)

So, can pagination inside `single.php` be done?

Comment: You can paginate a secondary Loop, though it tends to make navigation confusing IMO. What the site you reference is doing though is loading posts via AJAX and that is what you will need to do to duplicate that. I would suggest that you look at the [infinite scroll](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=infinite+scroll) posts here and see if you can get started.

Comment: Also, don't use `query_posts`

Comment: The AJAX I use needs working pagination in order to do its job. I have query_posts because, for some reason, it falls back to reloading the first page on single.php which is better than nothing (wp_query)

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77528/having-trouble-generating-pagination-links-on-custom-query/77545#77545 And: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73794/wp-query-post-at-custom-position/73928#73928

Comment: Already tried the former, now tried the latter, neither does it. I must be doing something wrong, I suppose the idea is to have the pagination as query (?paged=2 instead of /page/2/) but i don't know how to get there. Is it a canonical redirect I need to overwrite?

Comment: You say you have tried both techniques. Post that code.

Comment: whether or not pagination will work depends on the main query, single posts aren't paginated like archives, so page number links aren't going to work. WordPress receives the request for the second page and discovers it to be an invalid query, then redirects you back to the first page. I suggest passing a page number via AJAX to load your results if you want this to work, see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56349/4771) for a full working example of paginating a query via AJAX.

Comment: OK, here they are:

1) http://pastebin.com/rqVD9tYd

This results in numbered pagination but with the slashes that make the single.php loop useless.

2) http://pastebin.com/iDxRf8Y7

This results in numbered pagination but with all links pointing to current page and in some error enclosing showing: string(551) "Prev 1 2 3 [...] 67 Next". *String number varies.

Comment: Milo, that sounds neat but I think it's at least two levels above my competence. If it were just one, i would've given it a try ;D. Also, I rely on a plugin (infinite-scroll) and I don't know if it would be compatible with that method. If there's no easier way, than I should probably give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling canonical redirect (crudely) gets the job done.

Comment: An explanation would be useful.

Comment: Updated it. To remove canonical redirect, you add the following to functions.php:
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');