# Show single post then all posts (with pagination)

Tags: wp-query, pagination, single

On my `single.php` I would like to show the single post then list all the posts with a pagination.

I use the following code:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<!-- Show single post -->
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$all_posts_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 12, 'paged' => $page));
while($all_posts_query->have_posts()) : $all_posts_query->the_post(); ?>
<!-- Show all the posts -->
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php next_posts_link('older', '', 'yes'); ?>
```

As result I can see the single post then the first 12 posts and that all, no pager...

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination [does not work well will with secondary queries](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/77661/21376).

First, the ordinary pagination [functions depend upon the main query](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1524) in the `global` variable `$wp_query`. They won't work with secondary queries. There are already a number of questions here about that if you search the site.

Second, trying to paginate secondary queries tends to result in 404 status pages. That is because the query that runs before the template loads-- the "main" query-- is the one that determines what page to load and it *does not* know about the query written into your template.

I would suggest you use [`paginate_links`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) for your secondary query pagination. There are numerous examples of use here on this site, for example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73928/21376

Comment: Thank for these explanations @s_ha_dum, I understand well.