# Custom Post Types strange pagination problem

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, pagination

Have a strange problem with pagination, the query work fine when I'm in homepage, but if click for the next page I get a `404` error. Disabling permalinks settings, I saw that in the query string (when I move on to the next page), then I have `?paged=2` as query argument, but not `post_type=job_listing` (in this case). Here is my code:

```
global $wp_query, $paged;

if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) )
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
else
    $paged = 1;

if ( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) )
    $post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
else
    $post_type = 'job_listing';

$args = array(
   'post_type' => $post_type,
   'paged'     => $paged,
);

query_posts( $args );
```

And then I have a normal loop cycle and a `wp_reset_query()` at the end. 
The problem is that when open a pagination link the url look like `www.example.com/?paged=2` and not `www.example.com/?post_type=job_listing&paged=2` which works if I type it manually.

I tried everything to make it work but it keeps ignoring the `post_type` var in all pages.

Comment: Why are you using `query_posts()`? What **template file** is this?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is relate to this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108110/21376

Comment: If you're using `paginate_links()`, maybe you can pass your query var -> `paginate_links('add_args' => array('post_type' => 'job_listing'));`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is at the following lines:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) )
    $post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
else
    $post_type = 'job_listing';
```

Your `post_type` var will probably already being set, so you are calling some different post type (the one stored inside the `query_vars` array with the `post_type` key), which maybe does not have a second page and therefore leads you to your `404`. You can simply

```
var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_query'] );
```

or

```
printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', var_export( $GLOBALS['wp_query'], TRUE ) );`
```

depending on your debugging setup and take a look at the output to see what goes wrong in detail.

Aside from that, I'd

1. Use `get_posts()` or `new WP_Query()` to not mess up the main query (`query_posts()` is a private function reserved for core usage).
2. Set the query var fixed for that query:

   ```
   $post_type = 'job_listing';
   ```

Comment: Or just use `archive-{post-type}.php`, and not worry about custom-loop pagination issues.

Comment: @ChipBennett You know that this should be an answer, right? At least I know it's _the_ answer :)

Comment: I think it is, yes. But I'm still waiting for a response to [my comment above](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141564/custom-post-types-strange-pagination-problem/141696?noredirect=1#comment203073_141564), so that I can post it as the correct answer.